# I don't know the meaning of one character in a Python code

Tags: python

I wonder what is the signification of the ';' sign in the instructions

```
if l&lt;p:
if t&gt;0:
if int(num)&gt;=int(lst):
```

in the code of this question:
[Optimizing python code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747666/optimizing-python-code)

Maybe an error in the third instruction, ';=' instead of '!='

But I can't imagine the signification of the character in the two other lines.

Is there someone who can explain, please ?

Comment: Pythons syntax is sufficiently small to be learned with little study, and it's well documented. If you learn it, you'll spot erroneous code right away.

Comment: +1: For counter-acting the negative vote given

Comment: @Yavar Thank you for the upvote. On one hand, it's true that my question seems a little stupid; but on the other hand, I had done researches in vain and didn't know what to do more. - In fact, that's the kind of question on which there should be neither an upvote nor a downvote. It's an uninteresting question. But the truth is that someone downvoted this question and some others of mine as a reprisal because I affirmed that there are no varaiables in Python, and this didn't please him.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This actually should read

```
if l<p:
    ...
if t>0:
    ...
if int(num)>=int(lst):
    ...
```

It results from broken HTML.  The characters `<` and `>` are represented by the HTML entities `&lt;` and `&gt;`, respectively.  And somehow the web page you got this from got it wrong.

Comment: How stupid I am, it was evident but I was obsessed by the idea that the '&' character was connected to bitwise operations.  Upsetting speed , on SO. Thank you.